# Shepard interpolation algorithm

Tags: interpolation

Classic way to get a value based on other points in Shepard (Inverse distance weighting) method: 
$$F(x,y) = \Sigma_{k=1}^{N}w_{k}(x,y)f_{k} / \Sigma_{k=1}^{N}w_{k}(x,y) $$
where $w$ can be compute as some expression with metric (euclidian for example).

The paper *Scattered Data Interpolation: Tests of Some Methods* by [Franke](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ccc3/2f1de1ca92d9045e6a5bdb72616b5d1e46a4.pdf) tells (p.5) that another way to get needed value is compute follows: 
$$F(x,y) = \Sigma_{k=1}^{N}w_{k} [f_{k} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}_{k}(x-x_{k}) +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}_{k}(y-y_{k})]/ \Sigma_{k=1}^{N}w_{k}(x,y)$$

But I do not understand, how can I coumpute this. For example I have sample: 
$$\mathbf{x} = [0, 2, 4] \\ 
\mathbf{y} = [3, 6, 5]
$$
and I need to get interpolated value for point $a = 1$.

How can I do this?

Comment: The second formula assumes that you know the gradient at every data point. By the way, your example does not describe samples of a bivariate function.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Is it mean that I cant reduce the second formula for my example?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Remove from second formula df/dy(y-y_k) and use only with (f_k + df/dx(x-x_k))?

Comment: Are you trying to perform 1D interpolation ?

Comment: I'm trying to completely figure out that technique.

Comment: I am trying to figure out your questions.

Comment: You need a $(x,y)$, not two data points, also interpolation on two data points dosen't make sense. Shepard's interpolation formulation, $S_q^p f \rightarrow f$ when $N \rightarrow \infty$.